# Can I go to Germany if I have a Schengen ban?

Tags: schengen, visa-refusals, schengen-visas

I violated some rules in Switzerland and they banned me from all Schengen countries for 12 years.

I have heard that if I get married and apply for family reunion the ban will be removed. Is this true?

I want to go to Germany for a family reunion.

Comment: I think you answered this yourself. You need to seek professional legal help.

Comment: Normally, [Expats](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/) deals with that kind of one-way travel. If you want to pick up residence in Germany because you are married to a resident, you should consult a professional.

Answer (score 1):

The German government **can** allow you into Germany even if the other Schengen states will refuse you a visa. But that does not mean it **will** happen.

Much depends on your nationality and the nationality of your spouse. A family reunion process can take years, and if the spouse is not a German citizen there are more conditions to consider.

As the comments suggest, find a German lawyer who specializes in immigration law.

Comment: Besides, depending on the rules you violated, you may be **refused** the family reunion. Even in Germany.